# Implicit conversion sequence from {} in a copy-initialization context for a type with an explicit default constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

*(Consider this question for C++17 and forward)*

[LWG issue 3562](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3562)<sup>(+)</sup>, whether `nullopt_t`'s requirement to not be DefaultConstructible could be superseded with the `explicit` explicitly-defaulted default-constructor of other tag types:

> ```
> struct nullopt_t { explicit nullopt_t() = default; };
> ```

was closed as not a defect (NAD), with the following rationale

> 2021-06-14 Reflector poll:
>
> Current wording prevents an implicit conversion sequence from `{}`.

<sup>(+) Note that this issue mentions both LWG issue 2510 and CWG issues 1518 and 1630, whose resolutions (changed/superseded) were tightly coupled.</sup>

Consider the following example:

```
struct my_nullopt_t {
    explicit constexpr my_nullopt_t() = default;
};

struct S {
    constexpr S() {} // user-provided: S is not an aggregate
    constexpr S(S const&)      = default;
    S& operator=(S const&)     = default; // #1
    S& operator=(my_nullopt_t) = delete;  // #2
};

int main() {
    S s{};
    s = {};  // #3
}
```

which I would expect is well-formed as the overload `#2` is not viable for the assignment at `#3`, as the default constructor of `my_nullopt_t` is `explicit` (meaning `my_nullopt_t` is moreover not an aggregate in C++17). I particularly thought this was governed by [[over.match.ctor]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.ctor#1.sentence-2):

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized, copy-initialized from an expression of the same or a derived class type ([dcl.init]), or default-initialized, overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization or default-initialization **that is not in the context of copy-initialization**, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. **For copy-initialization (including default initialization in the context of copy-initialization), the candidate functions are all the converting constructors** ([class.conv.ctor]) of that class. [...]
>
> **[class.conv.ctor]/1** A constructor **that is not explicit** ([dcl.fct.spec]) specifies a conversion from the types of its parameters (if any) to the type of its class. Such a constructor **is called a converting constructor.**

But given the reflector's comment above I'm probably mistaken. Is possibly [[over.match.list]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.list#1.sentence-2)

> In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed. [ Note: This differs from other situations ([over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy]), where only converting constructors are considered for copy-initialization. This restriction only applies if this initialization is part of the final result of overload resolution. — end note ]

governing this case via entry from [[over.ics.list]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.list#7)?

We may finally note that we also see compiler variance here, where Clang accepts the program whereas GCC rejects it (for C++11 through C++20) with an ambiguity error. GCC particularly seems to consider `#2` a viable overload, whereas Clang does not.

> GCC error: ambiguous overload for 'operator='

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/TKddTY9sY)

#### Question

- What standardese passages support's the reflector's rationale above, e.g. applied to the example above?

  - Is this then in support of GCC's rejection of the program above, such that Clang is wrong to accept it?

Comment: How [over.match.ctor]/1 is related to copy-initialization from `{}`? `{}` is not an expression at all.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Would we need to copy-construct the value type parameter in `S& operator=(my_nullopt_t)` (if it is to be a viable candidate)? As I mention I'm likely missing something here, and I would be really happy for an enlightening answer :)

Comment: Copy-construct?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer My (probably ill-informed) thoughts where that `{}` is (somehow viable) to construct a `nullopt` temporary object, which is used as an argument to `S& operator=(my_nullopt_t)`, where the parameter type is a non-reference type that would arguably require to be _copy-constructed_ from the temporary `nullopt` object.  Is this not a copy-initialization context? But again, I'm obviously misunderstanding this, and would be grateful for an explanation of how there's an implicit conversion sequence from `{}` to an overload to a tag type with explicit default constructor.

Comment: (There's also the compiler variance between Clang and GCC, adding to the confusion.)

Comment: _Is this not a copy-initialization context?_ Parameter initialization is copy-initialization. Where does a temporary object come from? `S& operator=(my_nullopt_t)` parameter type is not reference.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But wouldn't `S& operator=(my_nullopt_t)` be viable only if `{}` is _first_ used to default-initialize a temporary `my_nullopt_t` object? After which this temporary (even if not materialized) would be the argument to the function call to `operator=(...)`, which has a single value type parameter who initialization falls under a copy-initialization context _for constructing that value type parameter_ from the temporary argument?

Comment: _`{}` is first used to default-initialize a temporary `my_nullopt_t` object_ [dcl.init] says that if the initializer is _braced-init-list_, then list-initialization ([dcl.init.list]) happens. In [dcl.init.list], you reach https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.list#3.5

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Ah yes that should be entry point. But (ignoring my confusion above), does that then mean that both Clang and GCC are wrong here? Clang rejects `#2` above as even being viable, whereas GCC considers it viable, and particularly if it's actually the best viable function GCC fails hard due to, afaict, violation of [over.match.list]/1. Maybe clearer [in this commented demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mH8SO1Klc21s2sU6).

Comment: I don't know much about overload resolution, esp. what covers value-initialization triggered by list-initialization when comparing conversion sequences, but AFAIK `S const&` initialization from `{}` is direct binding, which is identity conversion, which is unlikely better or worse than initialization of `my_nullopt_t` from `{}`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm mostly wondering whether the `S& operator=(my_nullopt_t)` overload should even be a candidate, but it seems it may be from your value-initialization argument. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think Clang is correct since `#2` is not a viable function.

Comment: @xmh0511 I thought so to, but as highlighted in CWG 1228, #2 is actually viable in a copy-list-initialization context, but if it’s chosen as the most viable overload the program is ill-formed. Extremely confusing imo, but according to CWG 2118 ”The current rules are as intended”.

Comment: @dfrib `#2` is not viable function in this context, although the initial context is copy-list-initialization, however, according to [dcl.init.list#3.5], that is, the initialization ultimately turns to a default-initialization, which is also in the context of copy-initialization(note that the initial copy-list-initialization is also in copy-initialization context, see [dcl.init#general-13]). Incidentally, CWG1228 has said that "The current rules are as intended.", which means the current wording has no problem, it is exactly artificial intent.

Comment: @dfrib For the example in CWG1228, Clang and GCC have a divergence again. Clang selects `#2` while GCC reports an ambiguous error. see https://godbolt.org/z/54qEqqGY5. The divergence associates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326627/the-requirements-of-forming-an-implicit-conversion-sequence-are-contradictory question, namely, which can be a viable function. ....

Comment: ... At least, according to the current wording, I think from argument `{23}` to parameter type `MyStore const& s`, there can not have an **implicit conversion sequence** since `MyStore const& s = {23}` is **not well-formed**. I think this part that about how can an implicit conversion sequence form has a defect. A deleted function can also cause a program ill-formed, however, it should be a viable function on intuitive. Also, see [issue 4934](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4934).

Comment: @xmh0511 That's interesting, thanks. What is your view on [LWG issue 3562](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3562), which was closed as NAD? The rationale for `nullopt_t` to not look like all other tag types was states as [paraphrased]: "it could allow empty-braces in copy-list-init leading to ambiguous overloads". If you argument above holds, however, this should be an issue, right?

Comment: @dfrib That may be associated with https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is right, and Clang and MSVC are wrong. This is highlighted in:

- [CWG1228: Copy-list-initialization and explicit constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1228)

which was also closed as NAD.

Somewhat surprisingly, the rules regarding `explicit` constructors differ between copy-list-initialization ([over.match.list]) and copy-initialization ([over.match.copy]) [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### 1228. Copy-list-initialization and explicit constructors
>
> - Section: 12.2.2.8  [over.match.list]
> - Status: NAD
> - Submitter: Daniel Krügler
> - Date: 2010-12-03
>
> The rules for selecting candidate functions in
> copy-list-initialization (12.2.2.8 [over.match.list]) differ from
> those of regular copy-initialization (12.2.2.5 [over.match.copy]): the
> latter specify that only the converting (non-explicit) constructors
> are considered, while the former include all constructors but state
> that the program is ill-formed if an explicit constructor is selected
> by overload resolution. **This is counterintuitive and can lead to
> surprising results.** For example, the call to the function object p
> in the following example is ambiguous because the explicit constructor
> is a candidate for the initialization of the operator's parameter:
>
> ```
> struct MyList {
>   explicit MyStore(int initialCapacity);
> };
>
> struct MyInt {
>   MyInt(int i);
> };
>
> struct Printer {
>   void operator()(MyStore const& s);
>   void operator()(MyInt const& i);
> };
>
> void f() {
>   Printer p;
>   p({23});
> }
> ```
>
> #### Rationale (March, 2011):
>
> **The current rules are as intended.**