# the requirements of forming an implicit conversion sequence are contradictory

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

[over.best.ics.general] p1 says

> An implicit conversion sequence is a sequence of conversions used to convert an argument in a function call to the type of the corresponding parameter of the function being called. **The sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in [conv], which means it is governed by the rules for initialization of an object or reference by a single expression ([dcl.init], [dcl.init.ref])**.

[over.best.ics.general] p9 says

> If no sequence of conversions can be found to convert an argument to a parameter type, an implicit conversion sequence cannot be formed.

[conv.general] p3 says

> An expression E can be implicitly converted to a type T **if and only if the declaration T t=E; is well-formed**, for some invented temporary variable t ([dcl.init]).

Consider this example

```cpp
struct A{
  A(int) = delete;
};
struct B{
   B(int) {}
};
void fun(A);  //#1
void fun(B);  // #2
int main(){
    fun(0);  // #3
}
```

Since, `A t = 0;` is ill-formed, hence the expression "0" cannot be implicitly converted to a type `A`, hence, it could arguably say we cannot find an implicit conversion that converts "0" to type `A`. So, according to [over.best.ics.general] p9, it cannot form an implicit conversion sequence for `#1`. However, this interpretation does not conform the most implementations, which process the example as an ambiguity. Even though [over.best.ics.general] p2 intends to avoid to concern these properties it didn't talk about(i.e. `#1` is a viable function)

> Implicit conversion sequences are concerned only with the type, cv-qualification, and value category of the argument and **how these are converted to match the corresponding properties of the parameter**.

However, since the invented declaration is ill-formed; the implicit conversion cannot be done, Isn't it exactly about **how these are converted to match the corresponding properties of the parameter**? I think these rules about how can an implicit conversion sequence be formed are contradictory. Is it considered a defect?

Comment: Good question, but it might be better suited to a discussion thread than someone providing a definitive answer. You might want to email std-discussion@lists.isocpp.org

Comment: Short answer: ambiguity is checked **before access**. If you mark a function deleted, it means you want an error if it could be called. In that simple, it is artificial as **if you don't want conversion**, you would use `explicit` or not define that constructor at all.

Comment: @Phil1970 There is no access violated in this example. *If you mark a function deleted, it means you want an error if it could be called.* I know that meaning. We just talk about the issues of these rules themself. I said, from these rules, we cannot read the artificial intents as you said in your comment.

Comment: @xmh As far as I understand, **there is a conversion from `int` to `A`** even though it is deleted thus `A t = 0;` is well-formed and there is an ambiguity as observed. At that point, the fact that a function is deleted, has not yet been considered. Not much different that what you would get if that constructor was private. I don't think it is a defect but you would also need to find the definition of **ill-formed** and **deleted functions** to see how it fit with that.

Comment: @Phil1970 *`A t = 0;`is well-formed* No, it's ill-formed, [dcl.fct.def.delete] p2 *A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.*, so `A t = 0;` is ill-formed. Incidentally, `T t = E;` shall be well-formed is the condition that can have an implicit conversion as per [conv.general] p3.

Comment: "the definition of ill-formed" [defns.ill.formed] *program that is not **well-formed***, In other words, at least, `well-formed` and `ill-formed` are mutual exclusion.

Comment: I think the following note in second paragraph of [over.best.ics] clarify how it works:
_[Note 1: Other properties, such as the lifetime, storage class, alignment, accessibility of the argument, whether the argument is a bit-field, **and whether a function is deleted, are ignored**. So, although an implicit conversion sequence can be defined for a given argument-parameter pair, the conversion from the argument to the parameter might still be ill-formed **in the final analysis**. — end note]_ Thus p3 would applied after selecting the overload and here ambiguity prevent selecting which one.

Comment: @Phil1970 First, I admit a deleted function should be considered as a viable function if some conditions are satisfied. I know that note, however, it is just a note but not a normative rule. What I'm concerning is the normative rules are contradictory here.